Merge asof missing values
Consider the following pandas:
df1:
user_id create_at
0   1   2023-01-01
1   1   2023-01-02
2   2   2023-01-01
3   2   2023-01-03
4   2   2023-01-05

df2:
user_id withdrawal_request_date
0   1   2023-01-03
1   2   2023-01-02
2   3   2023-01-01

I want to do a merge_asof BUT when I do, I lose the user with user_id=3. He is not in df1 so I lose him as you see below:
pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('create_at'), 
              df2.sort_values('withdrawal_request_date'), 
              by = 'user_id', 
              left_on = 'create_at', 
              right_on = 'withdrawal_request_date', 
              direction = 'forward')

user_id create_at   withdrawal_request_date
0   1   2023-01-01  2023-01-03
1   2   2023-01-01  2023-01-02
2   1   2023-01-02  2023-01-03
3   2   2023-01-03  NaT
4   2   2023-01-05  NaT

However, I would like to keep him in the final dataframe. The expected output should look like:
user_id create_at   withdrawal_request_date
0   1   2023-01-01  2023-01-03
1   2   2023-01-01  2023-01-02
2   1   2023-01-02  2023-01-03
3   2   2023-01-03  NaT
4   2   2023-01-05  NaT
5   3   NaT         2023-01-01

NOTE that my dataset is huge with thousands of users each doing a lot of activity so doing something like outer joins will not work here.
Any ideas?
DATA
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'create_at': pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-05'])
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [1, 2, 3],
    'withdrawal_request_date': pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-03', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-01'])
})


So what would be the exact expected output?

You can't perform what you want directly with a merge_asof. A merge_asof is anyway a left join.
What you can do however is post-process the output of the merge_asof to add the missing user_ids with help of isin and concat:
tmp = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('create_at'), 
                    df2.sort_values('withdrawal_request_date'), 
                    by='user_id', 
                    left_on='create_at', 
                    right_on='withdrawal_request_date', 
                    direction='forward')

out = pd.concat([tmp, df2[~df2['user_id'].isin(tmp['user_id'])]],
                ignore_index=True)

Output:
   user_id  create_at withdrawal_request_date
0        1 2023-01-01              2023-01-03
1        2 2023-01-01              2023-01-02
2        1 2023-01-02              2023-01-03
3        2 2023-01-03                     NaT
4        2 2023-01-05                     NaT
5        3        NaT              2023-01-01


I came up with a way to do it. Any more efficient answers are of course welcome!
This is my method:
df1 = df1.sort_values('create_at')
df2 = df2.sort_values('withdrawal_request_date')

merged_df = pd.merge_asof(df1, 
                          df2, 
                          by='user_id', 
                          left_on='create_at', 
                          right_on='withdrawal_request_date', 
                          direction='forward')


missing_withdrawals = df2[~df2['user_id'].isin(merged_df['user_id'])]
missing_withdrawals['create_at'] = pd.NaT
final_df = pd.concat([merged_df, missing_withdrawals], ignore_index=True)


Looks like you found the approach by yourself ;)

@mozway I had to post it here to get the inspiration though! It happens a lot to me :P

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'create_at': pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-05'])
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'wdate': pd.to_datetime(['2023-01-03', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-01'])
})
df11 =df1.sort_values('create_at')
df22 =df2.sort_values('wdate')

# Merge using merge_asof
merged = pd.merge_asof(df11,df22, 
                       by='id', 
                       left_on='create_at', 
                       right_on='wdate', 
                       direction='forward')

'''
merged :
   id  create_at      wdate
0   1 2023-01-01 2023-01-03
1   2 2023-01-01 2023-01-02
2   1 2023-01-02 2023-01-03
3   2 2023-01-03        NaT
4   2 2023-01-05        NaT
'''
# Find users in df2 not present in the merged result
missing_users_in_df2 = df2[~df2['id'].isin(merged['id'])]
'''
missing_users_in_df2 :
   id      wdate
2   3 2023-01-01
'''
# Append the missing users to the merged result
final_result = pd.concat([merged, missing_users_in_df2]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(final_result)
'''
   id  create_at      wdate
0   1 2023-01-01 2023-01-03
1   2 2023-01-01 2023-01-02
2   1 2023-01-02 2023-01-03
3   2 2023-01-03        NaT
4   2 2023-01-05        NaT
5   3        NaT 2023-01-01
'''

